# Assign stylemap to a individual vector

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to be able to specify the style of a vector individually. So what I did is this:

```
vectorLayer.features[1].style = {fillColor: "#8e0303", pointRadius: Math.random() * 50};
vectorLayer.redraw();
```

I got this from here: [http://jsfiddle.net/*DR*/Udd4e/31/](http://jsfiddle.net/_DR_/Udd4e/31/)

However, I want to specify a `StyleMap` instead of a `Style`

Something like this

```
var my_style = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default" : new OpenLayers.Style({
         ...
     }),
    "select":new OpenLayers.Style({
         ...
     }),
)};
```

And assign that as the style (stylemap) of the vector.
Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Jenia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be assigned for individual map objects, but try to think from the other direction: You can specify a mapstyle with more 'intelligence' that picks the style depending on the current map feature and it's attributes. See http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html and have a look e.g. to this webmap conditional styling for example: http://www.opennet-initiative.de/map/